# Custom character format properties with Microsoft Rich Edit control

Tags: c++, winapi, richedit

I need to implement a couple of app-specific character format options in a WinAPI c++ program using the Rich Edit control. The control is created with the `MSFTEDIT_CLASS` macro, which evaluates to `L"RICHEDIT50W"`. I am loading it by explicitly loading `MSFTEDIT.DLL` on a Win10 system.

From a naive reading of the docs, the most straightforward way to add custom formats might be simply to turn the `dwCookie` member of `CHARFORMAT2` into a bit-sensitive value. I tried doing this, however, and I can't seem to get it to work. As a test, I simplified my code to the following:

```cpp
    CHARFORMAT2W cf;
    ZeroMemory(&cf, sizeof(cf));
    cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
    cf.dwMask = CFM_COOKIE;
    cf.dwCookie = 0x02;
    SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION | SCF_DEFAULT, (LPARAM)&cf); // Apply formatting
    CHARFORMAT2W test;
    ZeroMemory(&test, sizeof(test));
    test.cbSize = sizeof(test);
    SendDlgItemMessageW(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID(), EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&test);
```

The information returned in `test` correctly identifies font, size, and standard styles. But the `dwCookie` value coming back is always zero, despite that I explicitly set it to 0x02 above. Am I missing something about how `dwCookie` works? The documentation doesn't say much about how one might use it.

Is there a better way to do my attributes? They are "hidden" (but grayed out to the user of the control, not actually hidden like `CFM_HIDDEN` is) and "absolute" (which means the text will not scale along with other elements in the program). I'll probably show "absolute" as a slightly larger font size in the Rich Edit control, once I have a way of storing and retrieving it.

Comment: For the moment I got it to work using the `bAnimation` field with `CFM_ANIMATION`. But I'm going to leave the question about `dwCookie` open, since it seems like a more "proper" solution.

Comment: CHARFORMAT2A.dwCookie: Client cookie. This member is opaque to a rich edit control.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT exactly why the OP is trying to use it.  They want to store their own data in the RichEdit and then retrieve it. The data *should* be opaque to the RichEdit